# Fetching a string alone from a delimited string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a `#` delimited string `@str`. I want to fetch the entityname alone from that
I tried the below approach, it works, but there are many `CHARINDEX` I need to apply to make it work.
Is there any other simple approach with less code I can use here. Is it possible to pass the `CHARINDEX` functions as expression in TSQL

```
begin 
  declare @str varchar(3000) = ''
  set @str = 'ref.products,0#dbo.sales,55#mdm.claims,78'

  SELECT value, 
    SUBSTRING( left(value,CHARINDEX(',',value)-1), CHARINDEX('.',value)+1, CHARINDEX(',',value)-1 )  entity_without_schema
  from string_split(@str,'#')
end
```

Expected output:

```
 value             entity_without_schema
 ref.products,0    products
 dbo.sales,55      sales
 mdm.claims,78     claims
```

Comment: use [parsename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) : `parsename(left(value, charindex(',', value) - 1), 1)`

Comment: @Squirrel  Very useful function for dot separated . Can we use this parsename only for dot separated ?or is that be used for # delimited or comma delimited

Comment: Why are you using this format with multiple delimiters? Looks like it should be a table valued parameter with 3 columns and 3 rows. Or if you must use a string it would be much easier to work with if you just passed a string with a JSON array of the 3 objects

Comment: agreed, It lands in my application via a python application .  but what you said makes sense, will be corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of *replace* and *parsename*:

```
declare @str varchar(3000) = 'ref.products,0#dbo.sales,55#mdm.claims,78';

select value, ParseName(Replace(value, ',', '.'), 2)
from string_split(@str,'#');
```